# Is my htaccess correct?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm trying to build a shopping cart using PHP & MySQL. Right now I'm in the process of creating product-detail pages. So this is how I set up my htaccess (located in the root folder):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My problem is I can only access a certain page if index.php is included. For example, `http://localhost/thegamingplace/products/details/1` displays a "Not Found" error, but `http://localhost/thegamingplace/index.php/products/details/1` works.

Can someone take a look at my htaccess and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Of course it would say "not found" your rewrite rule rewrites `/thegamingplace/products/details/1` to`/thegamingplace/products/details/1.php` my guess you want `index.php/$1` instead

Comment: did that, still not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

It works when tested at http://htaccess.mwl.be/

If it doesn't work make sure you have mod_rewrite installed and enabled.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Apparently the problem is the index.php isn't removed for every page on the site. For example, if I go to http://localhost:thegamingplace/ it works without index.php. But if I go to product pages - http://localhost:thegamingplace/products/details/1 then it doesn't work. My error message: The requested URL /thegamingplace/products/details/1 was not found on this server.

Comment: Actually, I fixed this by enabling mod_rewrite. Thanks!